# Excel VBA ODBC error on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I need some suggestion about excel and VBA.
My system is:

- MS SQL Server 2008R2
- Ms Excel 2003
- ODBC set and working

I've a vba code to retrieve data from a SQL server. The code is:

```
Sub update_supplier()

'CONNECTION STRING
cnnstr = "ODBC;DSN=XXX-XXXX-XX;UID=sa;PWD=xxxxx;Database=XXXXXXXXX"

'Query
qry_sup = "Select a.name from table a where a.postdate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'"

'UPDATE SHEET
Set sql_qry_sup = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=cnnstr, Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)), Sql:=qry_sup)
    sql_qry_sup.FillAdjacentFormulas = True
    sql_qry_sup.BackgroundQuery = False
    sql_qry_sup.Refresh
 End Sub
```

Well.. when i run this macro, i receive a GENERAL ODBC ERROR (run-time error 1004), and i'm sure is related to the BETWEEN option in the query..

Infact.. If ' change my query to

```
qry_sup = "Select a.name from table a where a.postdate > '2013-01-01'"
```

the vba work fine..

I'm also try the following

```
qry_sup = "Select a.name from table a where (a.postdate >= '2013-01-01' and a.postdate <= '2013-12-31')"
```

but i receive the same ODBC general error (run-time error 1004)

Have any suggestion or information about this issue??

Comment: Does your query work in SQL server (without using Excel)? Then it's your query, e.g. the dates formatting (you provide dates as string).

Comment: It could be your regional settings, 2013-01-01 is 2013-01-01 in both YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-DD-MM format, but 2013-12-31 is a bad date in YYYY-DD-MM format.  Try changing it to YEAR(a.postdate) = 2013?

Comment: @MP24 => The query work fine in my SQL Server

Comment: Are your date range values static or created dynamically from code?

Comment: @RichardHansell The format date is correct. The sql server (better.. this db on my sql server..) want the date in 'YYYY-MM-DD'. My query is between the first of jenuary (2013-01-01) and the 31 of december (2013-12-31). The YEAR(2013) could be a solution... But the goal is create a excel sheet where a user can set a range of date, maybe different from "between 2013-01-01 and 2013-12-31" and maybe across two year (E.g from 2013-10-01 to 2014-06-01)...

Comment: @avb => Now the date are static... directly in vba code.. But the goal is create a sheet where the user can set a date range.. In this case the date range will be dynamic (i hope....)

Comment: Try changing ODBC to OLEDB in your cnnstr

Comment: I have plenty of queries like this, working, but Excel 2007+ and server 2012, never got this error, @RichardHansell even if it works it is not sargeable so it may affect performance

Comment: I was only suggesting the YEAR(a.postcode) as a test to see if this is what is causing the underlying issue, not as a long-term solution.  Another suggestion would be to try more explicit dates, e.g. BETWEEN '1-Jan-2013' AND '31-Dec-2013' but also not as a long-term solution, just to test the date format isn't the problem.

Comment: Try also this:  "select * from (values(1))v(v) where '2013-01-01' between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'", it is independent from real tables

Comment: @RichardHansell The yaer(a.postdate) work in VBA.. and also work if i set only a date (E.g. a.postdate < '2013-01-01') Any other method to get a date range (through between or throug condition a.postdate >= '2013-01-01' and a.postdate <= '2013-12-31') run in error..  Could be an xls 2003 vba limit?

Comment: How many records would the query return? Could it be that you only have records with postdate in 2014?

Comment: Just for fun could you try a.postdate >= '2013-01-01' and a.postdate <= '2013-31-12'?

Comment: @MP24 => The query return about 50 records.. But don't work even the record are 2 or 2000...

Comment: @RichardHansell => as i said before... the code  **a.postdate >= '2013-01-01' and a.postdate <= '2013-31-12'** in where condition return the same error code... ;-) It was my first try after the error by between condition...